# Android Studio Error (SDK)

Tags: adk

When I load my App, appear the next error:

> The path 'C:\Data\android\adt\sdk' does not belong to a directory.
>
> Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead: 'C:\Android\sdk' and will modify the project's local.properties file.

When this error appear, I can't run my 'app' in virtual device.

How I can fix that error?

Best regards, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Go to `'C:\Android\sdk'` and look if there's is SDK Manager.exe

If is not, you have to install, a easy solution is reinstall Android Studio.

Another option is download only the sdk and install in the folder. After that, in Android Studio, go `File > Settings` and search for `'Android SDK'`, and change the `Android SDK Location` to the location that you have manually installed the SDK